# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What's the problem in the code? I can't seem to get it.
The error shows:

`utils.ts:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`
and

`react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ChartComponent)> component`

I have attached the code. Whenever i run the code, the screen becomes blank and white.
After removing the <Line../> snippet the app runs fine so the error seems to be in that particular section. But i can't seem to understand what's the error.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { CryptoState } from '../CryptoContext';
import { HistoricalChart } from '../config/api';
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CircularProgress, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container:{
    width: "75%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 25,
    padding: 40,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]:{
      width: "100%",
      marginTop: 0,
      padding: 20,
      paddingTop: 0,
    },
  },
}));

const CoinInfo = ({ coin }) => {

  const [historicalData, setHistoricalData] = useState();
  const [days, setDays] = useState(1);

  const { currency } = CryptoState();

  const fetchHistoricalData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(HistoricalChart(coin.id,days,currency)) 

    setHistoricalData(data.prices);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHistoricalData();
  }, [currency, days]);

  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary : {
        main: "#fff",
      },
      type: "dark",
    }
  });
  
  const classes = useStyles();

  //console.log("data",historicalData);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <div className = {classes.container}>        
        {!historicalData ? (
          <CircularProgress
            style={{ color: "#40E0D0" }}
            size={250}
            thickness={1}
          />
        ): (
          <>
            <Line
              data={{
                labels: historicalData && historicalData.map((coin) => {
                  let date = new Date(coin[0]);
                  let time = 
                          date.getHours() > 12
                            ? `${date.getHours() - 12}:${date.getMinutes()} PM`
                            : `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()} AM`;
                  return days===1?time: date.toLocaleDateString();
                })
              }}
            />
          </>
        )}

      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default CoinInfo
```

Output of console.log("data", HistoricalData):
[image: Output]

Comment: can you do a `console.log(historicalData)` to see how the array looks?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying [@mocherfaoui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18457414/mocherfaoui) . I have added the output as an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before return() simply add

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
 Chart.register(...registerables);
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the **react-chartjs-2** source code, and there seems to be a bug in props of the root **Chart** component.

You need to add a `datasets` field to the object you pass as `data` prop. It should be an array, and later will be mapped by one of the library's inner functions. (probably that's where the error is coming from)

Like the documentation:

```
 const data = {
labels: labels,
datasets: [{
  label: 'My First dataset',
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
}]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it. But now it's showing: 
`Error: "category" is not a registered scale.` 

I have included datasets in the data as follows: 
`datasets: [{ data: historicalData.map((coin) => coin[1]), }]`

Comment: Take a look at this link : https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/faq/registered-scale @LivingHell

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I solved the issue. Had to import and add the followings:
`import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';`
`Chart.register(...registerables);`